# SQLce Select query problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Wrote a Truck show Contest voting app, financial etc using sqlite. decided to write backup app for show day using ce 3.5. Created db moved to data directory, created tables configured dgridviews all is well. Entered some test data started management studio 08 ran select query against table and got null returns. Started app from vs studio and found that test data is gone. Re entered data ran query in MS data gone again.

If I use VS Studio can start and enter data, close app restart and data is still there, seems only when using outside tool on select query data deletes.

I don't know CE that well but this cannot be right.

```
select * from votes = delete * from votes??????????????
```

Comment: What is this? select * from votes = delete * from votes

Answer (score 1):

You're probably overwriting the database during your build.

Comment: I leave visual studio running and start MS, tableadapters perform a select query and they donot delete data. MS does delete data on select query

Comment: Check whether the file gets deleted, perhaps using `procmon`.

Comment: Metafore by typing select * from votes actually does del * from votes

Comment: Check whether the file gets deleted, perhaps using procmon --

The .sdf File? That stays intact except for data